# reducing opacity of images on a repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a repeater control that has one image and link button per item template.

What I would like to do is when a link button is clicked, each image except for the one related to the click goes to 50% opacity.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Categories" runat="server" OnItemCommand="showSubCat_itemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <div class="catListing">   
       <img class="RepeaterImage" src="/images/<%#Eval("imageUrl").ToString()  ?? "" %>"/>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="showSubCats" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'/>   
       </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is my repeater, I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('[ID*="showSubCats"]').click(function () {
    debugger;
       $(".RepeaterImage").not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.4 }, 300);
       $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);

    });
</script>
```

Nothing happens when any of the showsubcats link buttons are clicked. I'm guessing i might be on the wrong track!

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute in the html-markup for this `asp:LinkButton` will not be `showSubCats`.
I recommend you set `CssClass="showSubCats"` on the `asp:LinkButton`, and then use this javscript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.showSubCats').click(function () {

       $(".RepeaterImage").not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.4 }, 300);
       $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks - I am getting a response on the click now (I put an alert in to check). none of the images are reducing in opacity however.

Comment: That I don't know why, jQuery syntax seems fine. Even if I would probably skip `.stop()`, or  pass parameters to the function:
`.stop(true,true)`